# What's a "happy birthday"?

Tags: terminology, marvel-vs-capcom-3

In at least the Marvel vs. Capcom 3 (and UMvC3) community, commentators of a match may exclaim this consistently when a certain event occurs. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terminology occurs when you land a hit on two of your opponent's characters in this game.

The term apparently according to some sources happened to a professional player during a tournament on his birthday and since then it's become a thing.

Refer to this for more information:

> http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/637240-/63078993

Comment: This answer would be better if it were made clear that it's the same hit that hits more than one of your opponent's characters, it's probably no longer specific to this game, and it particularly refers to a combo, rather than a stray hit.

Comment: @NiteCyper While not specific to this game, this game is where it happens most often.  It's definitely not applicable in 1v1 character games.